# 'ion-slide' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, ionic3

1. If ‘ion-slide’ is an Angular component, then verify that it is part
   of this module.
2. If ‘ion-slide’ is a Web Component then add ‘CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA’
   to the

I’m using ion-slide as part of a component template but getting this error when trying to use that component
by importing the ComponentsModule.

Comment: here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309846/ionic-4-ion-slide-is-not-a-known-element/54329840#54329840

Answer (score 1):

in your -- component.module.ts import ionic module like this
`import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular'`
then add the it to the imports like this `imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(ComponentsModule)],`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a solution for `Ionic-4` you can see at this SO issue: [Ionic 4: 'ion-slide' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309846/ionic-4-ion-slide-is-not-a-known-element/54577906#54577906).

Answer (score -2):

You can use ion-slides as per on its documentation so please prefer this link for ion-sildes : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/

Comment: The link itself is not an answer.