# Ionic 4: 'ion-slide' is not a known element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using ion-slides in a new component.

carousel.component.html

```
<ion-slides pager="true" >
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

carousel.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.scss']
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

But when I use this component `<app-carousel></app-carousel>` inside my Ionic page, I get the following error:

```
'ion-slide' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-slide' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-slide' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<ion-slides pager="true" >
  [ERROR ->]<ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
"): ng:///SharedModule/CarouselComponent.html@1:2
'ion-slide' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-slide' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-slide' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  [ERROR ->]<ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: are you adding  IonicModule.forRoot() to your imports of AppModule ?

Comment: You need to declare your CarouselComponent in you app.module.ts in the declarations: [....., CarouselComponent]

Comment: Of course I have done that. There is no issue with my carousel component as I 1st tested carousel component by injecting into another component which was working fine. It got issue as soon as I added ion-slides

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to `schemas` in `NgModule`.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  ...
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})

export class YourModule {}
```

Comment: I was able to solve it by adding IonicModule.forRoot() to imports array. But now I tried your solution and it also solves the issue. Wondering what is the perfect solution.

Comment: `IonicModule.forRoot()` need to be only in one place, in `AppModule` if you have another module it need to be only `IonicModule` without `.forRoot()`.

Answer (score 2):

this error is resolved adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA on components.module.ts on where you have your components, for example "slides", not on app.module.ts on src/app/app.module.ts, it resolve this bug for me.

My structure it's:
-src/app/pages/welcome/welcome.page.html
i have module "slides" on src/app/components/slides
and the component module collect on:
-src/app/pages/components/components.module.ts 
you deed update like:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SlidesComponent],
  exports: [ SlidesComponent],
  ...
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],
})
```

and for finish we need update the src/app/pages/welcome/welcome.module.ts like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [WelcomePage],
})
```

with all updated must be work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `IonicModule.forRoot()` to the parent module of my component helped to solve the issue.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in your module file..

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA }  from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `IonicModule.forRoot()` to the parent module (`app.module.ts`) and add `IonicModule` to the Module that holds your component that adresses ion-slide

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
  ]
})
```

your component module (or `shared.module.ts`):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule,
  ]
})
```

derived from https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17232

Comment: Please comment on downvoting.